# How to get the first characters before a blank space in a post code in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a column in a pandas dataframe with post codes sometimes they have 4 digits before the blank space sometimes 3 i.e.

```
 NE5 2NY
 NE49 9PB
```

What would be the regex to use to replace these strings with only the characters before the blank space?

Comment: If you want to match the first word before a blank space you don't really need a regular expression, you can just do `line.split()[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\w{3,4}
```

Explanation:

1. `^` - start from the beginning of the string
2. `\w` - letters or numbers
3. `{3,4}` - exactly *3* or *4* of them

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5Cw%7B3%2C4%7D&test_string=NE5%202NY%0ANE49%209PB&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: To avoid matching `NE495` you can use a word-boundary `\b` at the end.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes, and a positive lookahead for a space after that maybe? [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) If OP says that there are also invalid records, I would add such restriction to filter them. Until then - it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use string splitting.

```
x = 'E14 7PZ'

y = x.split(' ')
y[0] = 'E14'
y[1] = '7PZ'
```

This will help you deal with postcodes like "E1 9YZ"

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*\s
```

1. **.*** - any character 0 or more times
2. **\s** - whitespace

Answer (score 0):

This one will handle the presence or otherwise of a space in the middle. You want to contents of the first group...

^([a-zA-z]{1,2}\d{1,2})\s*\d[a-zA-z]{2}

[Click here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(%5Ba-zA-z%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%5Cs*%5Cd%5Ba-zA-z%5D%7B2%7D&test_string=NE5%202NY%0ANE49%209PB%0ADN32LN&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to upload it because in my case was important not to depend on the number of characters I must select, so:

`^[a-z]+(?=\s)`

`^\w+(?=\s)`

#### Text example:

**korg** m3-m xpanded

- `^` -> begining
- `[a-z]` -> all characters from a to z
- `\s` -> Any space, tab or linebreak character
- `(?=\s)` -> Matches all described before only when it is followed by space